# JBoss EAP on Eclipse does not have jndi service

Tags: eclipse, configuration, jboss, ejb, jndi

I was trying to follow some EJB tutorial, most of them started talking about JNDI, and I am having trouble to get the service running on the JBOSS AS.

I have tried both the community and EAP version of JBoss in Eclipse, but both fails.

So now whenever I run lines like `BeanRemote beanRemote = (BeanRemote) context.lookup("somecontext");` it throws these error.

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

well of course it is caused by the port not opened, but I think its because the Jboss server is not providing the service, although its web port and admin port 8080 and 9990 is working fine.

I am using eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0, I have downloaded the Red Hat JBoss developer Studio. I added the server via the "New Server" wizard, then downloaded the server runtimes within the wizard. However there just seems no way to configure jndi, nor can I find any file that is related to jndi or jnp in the downloaded path. The XML configuration showed that only Management 9990 and Web 8080 port is open.

I don't understand why is this not enabled by default, and I don't know what to do. Is JNDI configurable somewhere in the management console? please help

Comment: You are getting this error because it looks like you're using a client that has been built to work with a much older version of JBoss AS.

Comment: @SteveC So you mean JNDI is like an outdated technology now? Or is EAP 7.0 too old? And Yes I am working with EAP 7. The tutorial I am following is on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/. So What kind of technology are they using for EJB3.1 now?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out method of linking to jndi changed in EAP 7 from EAP 5

this [articles](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) shows the correct method.

jndi.properties has been changed to jboss-ejb-client.properties, and the standard config now becomes

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=yourhostaddress
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

and context lookup string has been changed to 
`ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>`